# how to merge a hotfix branch in simple git flow

Tags: git

a team works on a simple git flow with `release`, `develop`, `feature` and `hotfix` branches:

- `develop` is based on `release`
- `feature` is based on `develop`
- `hotfix` is based on `release`

to merge the `hotfix` branch they have these options:

1. merge `hotfix` into both `release` and `develop`
2. merge `hotfix` into `release` then merge `release` into `develop`
3. merge `hotfix` into `release` then rebase `develop` on top of `release`

which option is the best and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should merge `hotfix` into `release` (the branch it's based on), and then your `develop` branch should be updated based on `release` (the branch `develop` is based on) new state. And the same to `feature`: updated based on `develop`. Disclaimer: this is my opinion.

Comment: option #2 should be the best option because:

 - when merging develop in release you may get a clean history with fast-forward instead of a merge commit as in option #1
 - since develop is a shared branch, rebase in option #3 may cause problems when pulling